# Want to try Gnome DE on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: unity, apt, gnome

I have been using Unity for a while now, but I would like to try out Gnome 3 DE without reinstalling everything and still keeping my current setup.  I was wondering what is the difference between

apt install gnome 
apt install gnome-shell 
apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

and which would be the best choice for my purposes as stated above?  Also, I have check out the dependencies to these packages and noticed that I already have somethings installed (i.e. Python, some icons/themes, gedit, etc) that would install along with the packages.  Would the packages/apps I already have just overwrite/update/be omitted?

Thank You.

Comment: I would recommend that you try the other desktop environments, when booted from a DVD or USB drive, 'Try Ubuntu ...'. The reason is that there are some problems, when you mix the desktop environments, and it is very difficult to remove what was added without damage on the original desktop environment.

Comment: I did that already, but I can't really try out any tweaks or anything or see if video drivers will work and such

Comment: The video drivers should work with all desktop environments, but for example playing video will work better with a light-weight desktop environment, if you are near the limit, when problems start. Tweaks: some will work, maybe not all of them. Please backup your system before adding other desktop environments. Then you can test, and if there are problems you can restore to the previous system settings.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily switch DE's, just install the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` via:

```
apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

after that, you can select which desktop environment to use in the login screen.

`ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is a meta package which should install everything which is needed to make it run.

Comment: Ok. I will try after I backup my system. Let's say I like gnome better than unity and want to use it as a daily driver what's the best way to make full switch?

Comment: For installing it as your daily driver you should make a new installation vie a minimal-iso and install only the DE you want. But like i said you can switch it over in the login screen and simply don't switch back, o.k. this means you have a complete DE as bloat ware on your machine but navigate this way around a fresh installation.

Comment: how much space do you reckon unity DE would take up?

Comment: Thats hard to estimate, since gnome-desktop as well installs many things unity has bundled in as well, there might be an overlap, so best to estimate is to look at the size of disk-space taken after installation.

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanna test and easily remove after, just need to install gnome-shell.

the ubuntu-gnome-desktop will indeed not only install gnome shell but also every default application that comes by default in the Ubuntu Gnome flavor release:https://ubuntugnome.org/